# Does giving full path for Partial View increase performance?

Tags: c#

```
return PartialView() vs return PartialView("~/Views/Home/abc.cshtml")
```

I have removed all the view engines from my project except `RazorViewEngine`.

Just want to know which is better in terms of performance. Here the controller is `HomeController` and the view name is `abc.cshtml` which is inside `views/home` folder and the action name is `abc()`. I am using ajax to call the partialview.

> Edited: Since I have removed all the viewengines. I am assuming it
>   will only look into two folders. first the view folder  itself and
>   second the shared folder for the cshtml file. So if I give full path
>   will it  increase performance even if its in milliseconds.

Comment: Don't try to performance tune based on guess work or a "hard and fast" rule that someone on the internet gave you. Set *goals*, then *measure*. If you're not meeting your goals, then seek to *isolate* the performance hotspots. Do you really believe that (if there is a difference here) this specific change will make a key difference for your site?

Comment: Hi there. I did set a goal earlier. I am trying to load my page almost instantly as much as I can. my page's initial load was roughly around 10 seconds and on the second request it was almost instant. I ran some diagnosis tools and found the System.web.optimization and web grease was the main culprit. So i fixed them out and now the page's initial load in about 1.25 second and then the second load is about 20 ms on each request. I still want to reduce the initial load as much as up to 1 second. And yea I am gonna do a test on this too once I get my answer rather than experimenting on my own.

Comment: Did you try by precompiling your pages on deployment?

Comment: Sounds like your web app isn't "always on" but shuts down after some timeout. Please have a look at your IIS application settings, this is not related to your application but to the way your web server *hosts* your application.

Comment: my web app is at always on and yes I have precompiled my views before pubishing too.